# Page not loading fully after firing a jQuery ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am facing a strange issue where-in my webpage does not load fully after firing a jQuery ajax POST request. I have a webpage that gets some html data from server via web service. I used jQuery ajax method to get data. However some times the although the data is received fully, the status bar still shows progress bar and halts there. As soon as I click on page somewhere, the progress bar completes and full page is shown. The status bar shows it is loading some image and halts. My images are hardly 1-2 kb and 2-3 on the whole page.

Previously I had set async: false but then removed with no change. Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE CODE:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "WebServerice/WebMethod",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: {},
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response){
        $("#myDivID").html(response.d);
        if(response.d !== '') {
            $('#lnk').click(function(){
                alert('You clicked link');
            });
        }
    },
    error: function(oError) {
        alert(oError.responseText);
    }
});
```

Comment: @ashish don't use async:false it can block the complete UI , can you post your ajax code??

Comment: Updated question with code sample

Comment: @ashish is it coming to success properly??? can you do a alert in the if block

Comment: The response is coming. I get the HTML in div, but the progress bar in status bar is stuck. As soon as I click on the page, the progress bar disappears. I had put a debugger statement in success and it is fired correctly.

Comment: just curious but have you tried $.post('WebServerice/WebMethod', {});

Comment: have u tried checking with firebug, use firefox+firebug and click the 'Net' tab and check what are the requests that are causing the problem.

Comment: Firefox does not report any issues. It happens only in IE

Comment: Ah, and update. I tried in Firefox console (I cannot install firebug because I am using Firefox v4.0 b7). I have a statement in jQuery as:

$("#myTblID td:has(img[src*='MyImageName'])")

I am trying to check whether the column in table has any image with src = "MyImageName". This line is giving errors in Web Console. Can it be the cause of issue? If yes, what is the alternate code for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. So the issue is resolved. In my previous code, I had async: false in my jQuery AJAX call. I later on made it to async: true. On Win 7 with II 7 it worked fine, but not on Win Server 2k8 + IIS 7.5. I restarted the IIS and tested and it worked fine.

Thanks for your responses gov.